# Flow: Refining the value of one prop based on another

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

I have an autocomplete that can hold either a single value or multiple depending on whether the prop `multiple` is passed to it. If it is multiple, then the value it holds will at least be an empty array -- it will never be null. If it is a single-value autocomplete, then the value can indeed be null. I'm struggling to get this typed correctly so that the `onBlur` function passed to it knows what value type to expect depending on whether the `multiple` prop has been passed to the autocomplete.

[Here's a link to the live flow.org testing page](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAlgWwA5wE4AuyYAhgM5gBKApiQMZFR5yZgDketDbA3KqgQCe2amABqJGAFdqAFTABeMAG8w6ACYAuMADspmAEbU8YAL4DhogMqCdBABbUC6OgEkd2KQQCiAN2p28kqqBCR4AOZO2qq+kjLaAPwS0nJmZvxCImAAgl5wdCzYME7UVug64cUACszYZEEqYHA6AELSeInJMkEAfGC+cBrpqHQw5BS5BPmFxQSl5ZWi1AAeczrqFDT0BAB0AMKFzQEEADyT0ziz8xXVtfV9yqhgYE9Nre2KYAAU1No2do5nG4PF4-MdZABKRQPV7PBzoMg7bB3HbNNpSPA-HahCJOHaxFJgAA+RN0UhgMAhr3Mz1enHWxi+EO0WwYOwAcnB1KJHs9npwCBidGATuVPEQ0e0FMp4YjJRjTGBgD1qahzBYsucCpcSgBZcnOGpwOoNVTyjriOJyADaAF1of1Bup0plRFqZnqDegrKE5qb+lbtF0bfb1aNxjk8tqip6YM4wCs1hsqFxdgccEc7Gcox65vq4+gjSaADSRqbRq755w+kh+mHPAkyMhBq2yO2vV7mz4-P62BxOFzucVgwJQhT1sAASHQUG+AEJqNiwpFdo3qFCBULYWBZfirRQlNadsfd2uyKXFziV3uUrbt7vkca5e8MV9T-uqc8aS9+QFuZjmRTbYOS5Hlt03PBhVFEEJRfPBpV3c1FWVVV1VdMsLhjOYAHU8BIbARDwBpXlJVRMC9GNtCgSQyGoUtzU6VsHQGIZv1IsByILSidzwGR6LglsUjbe1x0dViOwKHQyCId0dRwvCCOMbsyIo4p+PRExTG0WSsOoXD8MIyEHS+V5OOcGNXknBIRR0ysvTeDTpSQpUVWeSdtGzctc2uRYHKlZRnJQz8+RGZppLAPYcGw9AHDKG5RCUJljNhTzMKufTFJMc1pV8B1JLIOBih2eBwi+XLrN8HYhm0PQKQhRUzPQGNpWomBaOQlVgtpfKiEi7BoocKt0G7Mc+hMvlUorEoMsIvyMRyvKwsKxcSrK4qAnCBx6o41TRCCoA). The errors I get appear on both of the `onBlur={...}` lines at the end of the below code sample. The errors are:

```
39:   | { multiple: true, onBlur: ValueT[] => void }
                                  ^ array type [1] is incompatible with null or undefined [2].
References:
39:   | { multiple: true, onBlur: ValueT[] => void }
                                  ^ [1]
38:   | { multiple: false, onBlur: ?ValueT => void }
                                   ^ [2]
39:   | { multiple: true, onBlur: ValueT[] => void }
                                  ^ array type [1] is incompatible with `ValueT` [2].
References:
39:   | { multiple: true, onBlur: ValueT[] => void }
                                  ^ [1]
38:   | { multiple: false, onBlur: ?ValueT => void }
                                    ^ [2]
41: const AutocompleteWrapper = ({ multiple, onBlur }: AutocompleteWrapperT) => (
                                   ^ boolean literal `true` [1] is incompatible with boolean literal `false` [2].
References:
39:   | { multiple: true, onBlur: ValueT[] => void }
                    ^ [1]
38:   | { multiple: false, onBlur: ?ValueT => void }
                    ^ [2]
43:     ? <AutocompleteMulti onBlur={onBlur} />
                                    ^ Cannot create `AutocompleteMulti` element because `ValueT` [1] is incompatible with array type [2] in the first argument of property `onBlur`.
References:
38:   | { multiple: false, onBlur: ?ValueT => void }
                                    ^ [1]
20: type AutocompleteMultiPropsT = { onBlur: ValueT[] => void }
                                             ^ [2]
```

```
type ValueT = { id: number }
type SyntheticInputEventT = { target: { value: ?ValueT } }

type AutocompleteSinglePropsT = { onBlur: ?ValueT => void }

class AutocompleteSingle extends React.Component<AutocompleteSinglePropsT> {

  onBlur = (e: SyntheticInputEventT) => {
    this.props.onBlur(e.target.value || null)
  }

  render(): React.Node {
    return <input onBlur={this.onBlur} />
  }
}

type AutocompleteMultiPropsT = { onBlur: ValueT[] => void }
type AutocompleteMultiStateT = { value: ValueT[] }

class AutocompleteMulti extends React.Component<AutocompleteMultiPropsT, AutocompleteMultiStateT> {
  values: ValueT[]

  onBlur = (e: SyntheticInputEventT) => {
    if (!e.target.value) return
    this.values = [...this.values, e.target.value]
    this.props.onBlur(this.values)
  }

  render(): React.Node {
    return <input onBlur={this.onBlur} />
  }
}

type AutocompleteWrapperT = 
  | { multiple: false, onBlur: ?ValueT => void }
  | { multiple: true, onBlur: ValueT[] => void }

const AutocompleteWrapper = ({ multiple, onBlur }: AutocompleteWrapperT) => (
  multiple
    ? <AutocompleteMulti onBlur={onBlur} />
    : <AutocompleteSingle onBlur={onBlur} />
)

const CmpWithSingle = () => (
   <AutocompleteWrapper onBlur={v => console.log(v ? v.id : null)} multiple={false} />
)

const CmpWithMulti = () => (
   <AutocompleteWrapper onBlur={v => console.log(v.length)} multiple />
)
```

I have also tried using `type="single"/"multiple"` rather than just the boolean `multiple` prop, but that had no impact. I also tried the following alternative approach to the defining the `AutocompleteWrapperT` union type, but this produced some additional flow errors:

```
type BaseAutocompleteWrapperT<V, M: boolean> = {
  multiple?: M,
  onBlur: V => void
};

type AutocompleteWrapperT =
  | BaseAutocompleteWrapperT<?ValueT, false>
  | BaseAutocompleteWrapperT<ValueT[], true>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flow has an [unfortunate destructuring bug](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/5259) where it does not maintain the relationship between multiple destructuring results. You can work around this by avoiding destructuring here:

```
const AutocompleteWrapper = (props: AutocompleteWrapperT) => (
  props.multiple
    ? <AutocompleteMulti onBlur={props.onBlur} />
    : <AutocompleteSingle onBlur={props.onBlur} />
```

[Working Flow Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAlgWwA5wE4AuyYAhgM5gBKApiQMZFR5yZgDketDbA3KqgQCe2amABqJGAFdqAFTABeMAG8w6ACYAuMADspmAEbU8YAL4DhogMqCdBABbUC6OgEkd2KQQCiAN2p28kqqBCR4AOZO2qq+kjLaAPwS0nJmZvxCImAAgl5wdCzYME7UVug64cUACszYZEEqYHA6AELSeInJMkEAfGC+cBrpqHQw5BS5BPmFxQSl5ZWi1AAeczrqFDT0BAB0AMKFzQEEADyT0ziz8xXVtfV9yqhgYE9Nre2KYAAU1No2do5nG4PF4-MdZABKRQPV7PBzoMg7bB3HbNNpSPA-HahCJOHaxFJgAA+RN0UhgMAhr3Mz1enHWxi+EO0WwYOwAcnB1KJHs9npwCBidGATuVPEQ0e0FMp4YjJRjTGBgD1qahzBYsucCpcSgBZcnOGpwOoNVTyjriOJyADaAF1of1Bup0plRFqZnqDegrKE5qb+lbtF0bfb1aNxjk8tqip6YM4wCs1hsqFxdgccEc7Gcox65vq4+gjSaADSRqbRq755w+kh+mHPAkyMhBq2yO2vV7mz4-P62BxOFzucVgwJQhT1sAASHQUG+AEJqNiwpFdo3qFCBULYWBZfirRQlNadsfd2uyKXFziV3uUrbt7vkca5e8MV9T-uqc8aS9+QFuZjmRTbYOS5Hlt03PBhVFEEJRfPBpV3c1FWVVV1VdMsLhjOYAHU8BIbARDwBpXlJVRMC9GNtCgSQyGoUtzU6VsHQGIZv1IsByILSidzwGR6LglsUjbe1x0dViOwKHQyCId0dRwvCCOMbtHzqbRZKw6hcPwwjIQdL5XhUxFOOcGNXknBIRXUysvTedF4OUQzUTg5CVWeSdtGzctc2uRZbKlByUSQpUVU-PkRmaaSwD2HBsPQBwyhuUQlCZPTYU8zCri0xSTHNaVfAdSSyDgYodngcIvnyizfB2IZtD0CkIUVYz0BjaVqJgWiXNQULaUKohouwWKHCrdBuzHPp9L5dKKxKLLCL8jE8oKiLisXMqKtKgJwgcRqOIo4pgu6oA)

Comment: Unfortunately my true case is apparently more complex because this approach still doesn't solve it. But it does indeed solve the case I posed in the question and is valuable infomration to know!